# read an array of numbers from text file into array in C

Tags: c

This is what is written into a text file ex. "123.txt":

```
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]
```

How do I go about pulling these numbers into an array?

My thoughts:

1. Open the file (of course)
2. Use some form of fscanf
3. Place that fscanf under a loop and assign numbers to the new array as the loop progresses
4. Close File

Any thoughts on how to do this is greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

EDIT 1:

Note I am factoring out the efficiency problem for strictly learning purposes on this question. Also, error detection is implied, but not included.

```
int* load( const char* filename ) {
     int i;
     len = 100; // How to find len of array?
     array[len];
     FILE* fp = fopen( filename, "r" )

     while( !feof(fp) ) {
        fscanf(fp,"%d, ",&array[i]);
            i++;
        }
        fclose(f1);
     return array;
```

My code here at the loop doesn't end.

Comment: You pretty-much hit it in your steps. Now all you need is the code. Error and boundary checking are always appreciated, btw.

Comment: Show us your efforts..

Comment: I have added code please take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

scanf functions are generally pretty slow. I would use fread and strtok.

```
stat file get size
allocate buffer
fread to buffer
while not end of buffer
strtok
array[index] = strtoul(buf, 0, 10)
loop
```

good example of strtok on man page link
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html

Answer (score -1):

Just a general way. you can change it as per your need.

```
FILE *file = fopen("filename.txt", "r");
    int integers[100];

    int i=0;
    int num;
    while(fscanf(file, "%d", &num) > 0) {
        integers[i] = num;
        i++;
    }
    fclose(file);
```

Answer (score -1):

Tried with redirecting the file to stdin. A weak code, still works.:p

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
freopen("fileName","r",stdin);
char arr[200];
int result[10],i=0;
do
{
    scanf("%s",arr);
    if(arr[0]!='[' && arr[0]!=']')
    result[i++]=atoi(arr);
}while(arr[0]!=']');

}
```

Comment: The downvoter, please explain your concern about the code. Is this not working in your machine?